# access rows with a common name from DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, data-science

Given data with rows and columns, how do i access rows that have a common name, for example in a cars sales data, i want the output to be dataframe of cars with "honda" in their name mind you honda has different models[image: car sells]

Answer (score 1):

you can filter it using `df.Series.str.contains()` function. This will return each row equal to `True` if it contains the value that we look for, and `False` if otherwise

for example, you want to get rows that contain `honda`. to get the DataFrame that contains 'honda' in columns `name` is :

```py
df[df['name'].str.contains('Honda')]
```